# Regex pattern to extract row

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have text file like the following:

```
some text 402115000518432  
402115000518432  97517518878      IDLE
some text
...
some text 402115001509990  
402115001509990  97517490827      IDLE
...
```

I want the entire row that "begins" with 40211 in an excel file. Desired output:

```
402115000518432  97517518878      IDLE
402115001509990  97517490827      IDLE
```

I was trying with the following code:

```
Dim pattern = "(?<=\s*)40211[^\s]*"
Dim i = 1

For Each line In File.ReadLines(RichTextBox1.Text)
            Dim match = Regex.Match(line, pattern)


            If match.Success Then
                sheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = match.Value
                i += 1
            End If
        Next
```

But the output is only the values starting with 40211, not the entire rows that start with 40211. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        pattern = "^(40211)"


        If match.Success Then
            sheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = line
            i += 1
        End If
```

you almost cracked it . Just reuse the `line` variable.

Comment: thanks. it works. But I have a problem now. I have edited my question. The 40211 characters appear in other places as well. But I am looking to grab the rows where it starts with 40211. I have edited the question. Any idea?

Comment: @slyclam just try `pattern = "^(40211)"`

Comment: Would you mind answering this question for me please?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30543061/excel-text-to-columns-using-vb-net?noredirect=1#comment49159090_30543061